# How do I get extents in my mesh

Tags: mesh, aabb

I am creating a AABB for collision detection. I need to calculate the extents for my model and also update them when my model moves. I calculate my min and max when I create my mesh and I use my position to reference the center.

Could someone please show me how to get the extents either with my min and max vectors or with an array of vertices.

Actually for more clarification I tried this

```
public Vector3f getMin() {
    return Vector3f.sub(pos, extents, null);
}

public Vector3f getMax() {
    return Vector3f.add(pos, extents, null);
}
```

The problem is that everything seems to be centered around the origin(0,0,0).
    The position is the position of the entity the AABB represents.

Comment: So just to clarify: You already have the min & max positions, and you're asking how to calculate the size of a bounding box from those?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Yes I am

Comment: How are you calculating `extents`? Why is the same method twice there? *How* is this code not working? Have you tried rendering/printing out the AABB? Are you sure that your min & max positions are calculated correctly?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Here is how I caluculate extents `this.extents = Vector3f.sub(max,min,null);` and everything is centered around the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the box that covers the whole mesh is simply the difference between the max and the min position: `vec3 size = max - min;`.

Now from that you can get the extents simply by halfing the size: `vec3 extents = size * 0.5f;`

Comment: I tried that. Still doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? How does it not work? What is the expected behaviour? You are giving us nothing to help you debug your issue.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: @MackybenJonah try including numbers in a concrete example. For instance "I have a cube mesh with these vertices: ... I calculate my min and max values as: ... When I use this size calculation I get the result X, but I expect the result Y instead" - that will help us identify where the problem is.